# node.js: any way to export ALL functions in a file en masse (e.g., to enable unit testing), vs. one by one

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, module

in node.js, is there any shortcut to export ALL functions in a given file? i want to do this for unit testing purposes, as my unit tests are in a separate file from my production code.

I know i can go through and export each function manually, as in:

```
exports.myFunction = myFunction;
```

But i'm wondering if there is a simpler/slicker way to do this.

(and yes, i realize for modularity reasons it isn't always a good idea to export all functions, but for unit testing purposes you do want to see all the little functions so you can test them piece by piece.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
// save this into a variable, so it can be used reliably in other contexts
var self = this;

// the scope of the file is the `exports` object, so `this === self === exports`
self.fnName = function () { ... }

// call it the same way
self.fnName();
```

Or this:

```
// You can declare your exported functions here
var file = module.exports = {
  fn1: function () {
    // do stuff...
  },
  fn2: function () {
    // do stuff...
  }
}

// and use them like this in the file as well
file.fn1();
```

Or this:

```
// each function is declared like this. Have to watch for typeos, as we're typing fnName twice
fnName = exports.fnName = function () { ... }

// now you can use them as file-scoped functions, rather than as properties of an object
fnName();
```

Comment: Thanks -- but that still means listing each function explicitly by name. So i guess there is no "export *" type of concept?

Comment: No, there's nothing like that. If you look at my now edited answer, you will see a method I have used to take care of this problem. This allows you to declare all your functions in the object, and still use them throughout the file.

Comment: Clever -- thanks. So the tradeoff here is not being able to call the functions directly by name anymore, and having to use the file.fn1() syntax instead.

Comment: Right. But at least you don't have to declare a long list of functions and then list them all again to export them. Edited answer to include yet another option.

Comment: Edited again. My favorite option is on top.

Comment: Hmm, i like the top method syntactically, but it didn't work for me -- calling the method via this.fnName() didn't resolve (TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'fnName'). The bottom method did work fine. I'm using node 0.4.7 if that matters.

Comment: Are you making sure to call your function after you have declared it? Also, try adding a couple properties to `this` and then log `this` to the console to make sure it works. Also, if you are inside another function, the context could be different, so `this` might mean something different. Try doing `var self = this` at the very top of your file, and use `self` instead of `this` to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: `...` gives me an error 'declaration or statement expected'

Answer (score 0):

Mixin objects is the answer.

This lib can help you: https://github.com/shimondoodkin/nodejs-clone-extend

```
//file1.js

var _ = require('cloneextend');
_.extend(this, require('file2.js'));
```

file1.js has now all exports from file2.js

Comment: the overhead of `_.extend` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do it. Parse the AST and look for top level function definitions, and export those.

```
const esprima = require('esprima')
const program = fs.readFileSync(__filename,'utf8')
const parsed = esprima.parseScript(program)
for (let fn of parsed.body) {
  if (fn.type.endsWith('FunctionDeclaration')) {
    module.exports[fn.id.name] = eval(fn.id.name)
  }
}
```